# Alternative to v8 for exposing C++ objects to JavaScript (on PowerPC)

Tags: c++, webkit, powerpc, javascriptcore, emscripten

I need to expose C++ classes (packed as shared libraries) to the magic world of JavaScript.

The most obvious solution is to use Node.js/v8. Problem is that it has to run on PowerPC (please no comments on this...) and - alas! - v8 doesn't run on PowerPC (the [v8-powerpc](https://github.com/ic/v8-powerpc) project seems to be dead).

I'm trying to understand if there's any other viable solution, at the moment some possibilities are:

1. [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten), which converts LLVM bitcode into JavaScript;
2. WebKit's [JavaScriptCore](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore), although I'm not sure it will work (I'll have WebKit on the PowerPC anyway)

I'm not a JavaScript expert and I actually feel quite lost, so these are my questions:

1. Is emscripten a valid solution? (have you ever used it?)
2. Can anyone point me to any documentation on how to expose C++ to JavaScript using JavaScriptCore?
3. Is there any other option, and/or which one would you adopt?

Many thanks,

Rippel

Comment: Just for clarity, the objective is to write a JavaScript application (running on a JS engine) using the C++ libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Qt has a port of webkit that runs on powerpc and it has a javascript engine that allows you to call C++ code.

[Qt: Making Applications Scriptable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/scripting.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Emscripten*. And I have used it and am using it.
Problems are:

- The JS/C community is IMO kind of suspicious/vary about *Emscripten* so you might not get much support there (usually the #emscripten IRC channel is pretty helpful).
- *Emscripten* compiles code fairly easy/well but you need to have a decend understanding of C to get a working solution. You will probably have to rewrite certain parts of your code to get it working as expected by your JavaScript engine (stuff like using main_loop, callbacks, etc.).
- Using *Node.js* you could also try to use the synchronous file api (see http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) - but I fear you would have to change the *Emscripten* file access emulation, as it is mostly coded for Browser usage, right now.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptCore has [JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/WebKit_JavaScriptCore_Ref/JSObjectRef_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback). It looks like this potentially involves a *lot* of boilerplate code to convert arguments in and exceptions out, though.

Answer (score 0):

Now Node.js DOES run on PowerPC. See [this github link](https://github.com/andrewlow/node) (I think it runs on any system with a powerpc processor that runs linux.