# How to pass an anonymous function as parameter from javascript to c++ on webkit?

Tags: javascript, c++, webkit

How to pass an anonymous function as parameter from javascript to C++, on webkit platform

example:

```
window.test('helloworld', function(){
    alert('ye');
});
```

The "test" is C++ injected into web for javascript, and javascript pass two parameters to C++

I want C++ call the second parameter which is anonymous function when C++ execute as asynchronous ?

Or C++ just receive parameter which type is String?

Comment: This previous thread may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157743/alternative-to-v8-for-exposing-c-objects-to-javascript-on-powerpc

Answer (score 1):

1. Add Custom method to DOMWindow interface(WebKit/Source/WebCore/page/DOMWindow.idl):

   ```
   ...
   interface DOMWindow{
     ...
     [Custom] void test();
     ...
   };
   ...
   ```
2. In WebKit/Source/WebCore/bindings/v8/custom/V8DOMWindowCustom.cpp, add a method in namespace WebCore:

   ```
   ...
   v8::Handle<v8::Value> V8DOMWindow::testCallback(const v8::Arguments& args){
     v8::Local<v8::String> str;
     v8::Local<v8::Function> jsFn;
     if(!args[0]->IsString() || !args[1]->IsFunction())
           return v8::Undefined();
     str = args[0]->ToString();
     jsFn = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(args[1]);

     v8::Persistent<v8::Function> pFn = v8::Persistent<v8::Function>::New(jsFn);
     pFn->Call(v8::Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 0, NULL); // Execute the passed in js function
     return v8::Undefined();
    }
   ```